# replacing subdomain from a list of columns

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have migrated a website using wordpress from one server to another. while the website is not in a beta phase but still have nearly 40 entries of subdomain included, some with different strings attached after ?, how can i removed the subdomain name from the 40 entries in my database to just the real domain?

Answer (score 0):

Download http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/. Job done. Just backup the database first, as a precaution..